# Dropping Pandas Dataframe Columns based on column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a Pandas dataframe df with extraneous information. The extraneous information is stored in the columnns that have names containing "PM". I would like to remove these columns but I'm not sure how to. Below is my attempt to do this. However, I received this error message: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'PM'. I'm not sure how to interpret this error message. I also don't understand why numpy is mentioned in the message since the dataframe df is a pandas object.

```
for j in range(0,len(df.columns)-1):
 df.iloc[0,j].str.contains("PM"):
   df.drop(j, axis=1)
```

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'PM'

Comment: Can you add some small data sample, 3 columns, 3 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Using an empty dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','ABCPMYXZ','QWEPMQWE','c','d'])
df
df = df[[i for i in df.columns if not 'PM' in i]]
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood, you want to delete columns, so initially you should store all the column names in a list. Next remove all the elements from the list which doesn't contain PM in it.

```py
columns = list(df.columns.values)
columns = [col for col in columns if 'PM' in col]
df.drop(columns=columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Careful removing elements of a list while iterating over it, it often leads to incorrect results, in particular when two consecutive elements should be removed.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` with `filter`:

```
df.filter(regex='^((?!PM).)*$')
```

This is the shortest solution here.

Comment: @jezrael No time. Edited it out